# R statistics per zone using raster::zonal

Tags: r, raster

I would like to calculate zonal statistics in areas that align with the graticules.

After getting a list of extents, the idea is to assign block numbers, because the raster::zonal function requires a raster layer with codes representing the zones.

When I try to fill the extent with a zonal number, the filled area does not correspond with the extent (see plot). Why is that?

```
library(raster)
library(foreach)

filename <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r=raster(filename)

xmin = seq(178000, 181000, 1000)
ymin = seq(329000, 333000, 1000)

e=foreach(j=ymin,.combine=c) %:% 
  foreach(i=xmin) %do% {
    e=extent(i,i+1000,j,j+1000)
  }


# this should be going into the foreach loop
n=length(r[e[[1]]])
r[e[[1]]]=rep(1,n)

plot(r)
plot(e[[1]],add=T)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just cropping out each zone individually with `crop(raster, extent)`? The output is a raster as well so you can get easy stats for that.

Comment: Thanks Ronny, but that has the same problem - gives the same plot if I plot extent of the cropped raster.

Comment: Henk, I might be wrong but I think the filled area does correspond with the extent. What you just get is filled values for the original raster extent. For the plotted area it is `xmin = 178400` and will be the same whenever you rich raster extent limits. One way to get around it might be also limiting zonal areas to the existing limits of the original raster `r`.

Comment: Thanks Majid, I think my question reduces to: how do I change values for a raster within a given extent? The extent plots correctly, but when I want to change the values within it according to raster::replacement it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think that fails basically because of the different extents. I provided a solution and hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? I've modified the extent of raster if you don't want to modify your fishnet.

```
library(raster)
library(foreach)

filename <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r=raster(filename)
extent(r) <- c(178000,182000,329000,334000 )

xmin = seq(178000, 181000, 1000)
ymin = seq(329000, 333000, 1000)

e=foreach(j=ymin,.combine=c) %:% 
  foreach(i=xmin) %do% {
    e=extent(i,i+1000,j,j+1000)

    n=length(r[e])
    r[e]=rep((j-i),n)#zonal stat instead of j-i?
  }
plot(r);plot(raster(filename), add=T, alpha=0.5, legend=F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a shapefile with QGIS containing the grid cells as a regular grid. Afterwards you can use the shapefile and your rasterfile with `raster::extract` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/extract) or even faster with `exactextractr::exact_extract` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactextractr/index.html)

Comment: Thanks Marcel. I will try it out, but my preferred solution is within R, using the raster::zonal function. My problem is basically getting the rasterlayer with codes representing zones that raster::zonal requires.

Comment: you can also use rgdal to make the grid within R - so you dont have to use qgis ;-)

Comment: :-) the thing is, I have the grid - via the extents. the problem is not the grid, but the (for me) unexpected behaviour when I apply them on a raster.